# Why does this route not resolve?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor

```
routes.MapRoute(
                "top", // Route name
                "{controller}/Casestudy/{action}"
            );
```

Anyone know why this routing doesn’t resolve to;

> /Auction/Casestudy/ABC/

The controller Auction is there, the Action ABC is there and the view is there?

Comment: Please show your other route definitions as well if you have any. Also are you sure that the controller class is called `AuctionController` and not only `Auction`?

Comment: It should work.As mentioned by Darin make sure the name of controller "AuctionController". "Home/Helloworld/Index" should match "{controller}/Helloworld/{action}"

Comment: What does "does not resolve" mean? Doesn't it resolve in an action link, doesn't it resolve when typing the URL in the browsers location bar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that you put your `"top"` route *after* your `"Default"` route (provided you didn't change that call to `MapRoute()`).

You need to ensure that your `"top"` route appears before you Default route, otherwise your `"Default"` route will surely match your tested URL and deliver a 404.

```
routes.MapRoute(
                "top", // Route name
                "{controller}/Casestudy/{action}"
            );

routes.MapRoute(
    "Default", // Route name
    "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
    new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
);
```

If those are switched up and your `"Default"` route comes first, then you'll have your route matching the `"Default"` route with `controller = "Auction", action = "Casestudy", id = "ABC"`.  Which is obviously not the intention.